# WiX "HTML embed code" iframe doesn't follow fixed position and z-index

Tags: html, iframe, css-position, z-index, velo

I'm trying to use the WiX "HTML embed code" feature in order to display an iframe on top of my WiX site. The sequence of steps I do is:

Enter Wix admin --> My Sites --> Edit Site

Click +Add --> Apps --> HTML

Increase the size of the gray rectangle so it roughly covers all the visible part of the window

In the 'HTML Settings' dialog:

Select 'Mode' = HTML code

Check 'Show on all pages' below

In the 'HTML / embed code' box, paste my code (see below)

Below the 'HTML / embed code' box, click 'Update'

Close the 'HTML Settings' dialog

In the WiX editor top-right click 'Save'

In the Wix editor top-right click 'Publish' (and confirm)

The code I paste is a piece of JavaScript that eventually creates an iframe. The iframe's style has a **fixed position** and a **very high z-index**.

Upon browsing the site, the iframe is actually created and displayed, but with two strange effects:

1. The position is set **not** relative to the whole window (as 'fixed' position should be), but rather relative to the original gray object representing the HTML app during the WiX edit.
2. Some elements of the original WiX template - hide sections of the iframe, regardless of how high I set its z-index to be.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you test by creating the iframe with just HTML/CSS and rule out the Javascript being the problem? (Wix may not fully support what you're trying to do)

Comment: I could test it, but in practice I need the JavaScript as well (e.g., for async creation of iframe plus other minor issues). Is there a way I can debug objects style values in real-time? I tried F12 with various browsers, but saw only some of the values, specifically not the z-index.

Comment: Understood - I was suggesting taking the script out of it to see confirm whether or not Wix can support what you're trying to do.

Comment: Were you able to figure out a solution to this?